# The free products of ﬁnitely many ﬁnitely generated groups are hyperbolic relative to the factors

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Are there any references how to show that:the free products of ﬁnitely many ﬁnitely generated groups are hyperbolic relative to the free factors. More precisely, how to show that
$G = A \ast B $ is hyperbolic relative to $\{A, B\}$?

Comment: This is almost obvious using the definition of relative hyperbolicity in Osin's paper "Relatively hyperbolic groups: Intrinsic geometry,
algebraic properties, and algorithmic problems", i.e. a linear Dehn function relative to $A$ and $B$. In the case of the free product, this Dehn function is $0$.

Comment: This is also clear from the definition of relative hyperbolicity from actions on fine hyperbolic graphs: it suffices to consider the action on the Bass-Serre tree.

Comment: @DerekHolt Hi! Why is the Dehn function is 0